# Porque o appenchild não está funcionando? as imagens não aparecem

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function JKP() {
    var jkpsort = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    var radjkp = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']")
    var resJKP = document.getElementById('resJKP')
    var img = document.createElement('img')
    img.setAttribute('id', 'foto')
    /*
    0 = pedra
    1 = papel
    2 = tesoura
    */
    if (radjkp[0].checked) {
        if (jkpsort == 0) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Houve um empate'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'pedra.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 1) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você perdeu'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'papel.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 2) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você ganhou'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'tesoura.png')
        }
    } else if ((radjkp[1].checked)) {
        if (jkpsort == 0) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você ganhou'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'pedra.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 1) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Houve um empate'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'papel.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 2) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você perdeu'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'tesoura.png')
        }
    } else {
        if (jkpsort == 0) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você perdeu'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'pedra.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 1) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você ganhou'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'papel.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 2) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Houve um empate'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'tesoura.png')
        }
        resJKP.appendChild(img)
    }

}
```

```css
header{
    background-color: rgb(154, 47, 197);
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto
}
body{
    background-color: rgb(77, 83, 167);
    
}
section{
    width: 500px;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
}
footer{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Jogo da Velha</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="JKP.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Jo-Ken-Pô!!</h1>
    </header>
    <section>

        <input type="radio" name = "radjkp" id = "pedra" checked >
        <label for="pedra"> Pedra</label>
        <input type="radio" name = "radjkp" id = "papel">
        <label for = "papel">Papel</label>
        <input type="radio" name = "radjkp" id = "tesoura">
        <label for = "tesoura"> Tesoura </label>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="JoKenPô!" onclick="JKP()">
        </p>
        <div id = 'resJKP'></div>
        
    </section>
    <footer>

    </footer>
    <script src = "scriptJKP.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelos testes que fiz no seu código, aparentemente as imagens do primeiro e segundo 'radio' não aparecem, apenas a do terceiro é exibida. Não deu para entender direito se esse é seu problema, se for o caso adicione mais detalhes a sua pergunta para facilitar.

Se for esse mesmo o problema, segue o código ajustado para aparecer as três imagens. Apenas removi o `appendChild` de dentro do `else` do terceiro 'radio' no seu JS, pois estava limitando e fazendo com que o `appendChild` fosse executado apenas quando o terceiro 'radio' estivesse selecionado.

```
function JKP() {
    var jkpsort = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    var radjkp = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']")
    var resJKP = document.getElementById('resJKP')
    var img = document.createElement('img')
    img.setAttribute('id', 'foto')
    /*
    0 = pedra
    1 = papel
    2 = tesoura
    */
    if (radjkp[0].checked) {
        if (jkpsort == 0) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Houve um empate'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'pedra.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 1) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você perdeu'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'papel.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 2) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você ganhou'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'tesoura.png')
        }
    } else if ((radjkp[1].checked)) {
        if (jkpsort == 0) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você ganhou'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'pedra.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 1) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Houve um empate'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'papel.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 2) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você perdeu'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'tesoura.png')
        }
    } else {
        if (jkpsort == 0) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você perdeu'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'pedra.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 1) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Você ganhou'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'papel.png')
        }
        else if (jkpsort == 2) {
            resJKP.innerHTML = 'Houve um empate'
            img.setAttribute('src', 'tesoura.png')
        }
    }
    resJKP.appendChild(img)
}
```

Comment: Consegui aqui amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Um erro muito pequeno que passou despercebido kkk